# How to set ModerationInformation.Status Values in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, splistitem, status

I have saved `$item.ModerationInformation.Status` information in HashTable `$DeletedItemsIDs` and recycled list items. After That I restored items from recycle bin and assign saved ModerationStatus information back to items, but items restored with "Pending" status. Whats wrong with this Powershell code? I can see the correct saved Moderation status info in variable `$deleteditemId.Value`

```
    // Saving Modeartion status info
  $DeletedItemsIDs = @{}

    foreach($item in $ListItems)
    {
       $DeletedItemsIDs.Add($item.ID,$item.ModerationInformation.Status)
       $DeletedItem = $item.recycle()       
       $DeletedItems.add($DeletedItem)
    }


// I do some stuff here and then restore as 

ForEach ($deletedGuid in $DeletedItems)
{
 $site_To_AddCT.RecycleBin.Restore($deletedGuid)
 $Recount++
}
    //Here assigning back moderation status info after restoring


      ForEach ($deleteditemId in $DeletedItemsIDs.GetEnumerator())
      {

       $Pageitem = $PagesLibrary.GetItemById($deleteditemId.Key)
       $Pageitem.File.CheckOut()
       $Pageitem["ContentTypeId"] = $Global:ctToAdd.Id
       $Pageitem.File.CheckIn("CheckIn automatically")
       $Pageitem.File.Publish("Published automatically")
       $Pageitem.ModerationInformation.Status = $deleteditemId.Value // whats wrong here
       $Pageitem.Update()
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$Pageitem.Update()` (or `.SystemUpdate()`) after assigning `ModerationInformation.Status`:

```
$Pageitem.Update();
```

You need to update the item after changing the metadata as well as after setting the Moderation Status. Your code should look like this:

```
$Pageitem = $PagesLibrary.GetItemById($deleteditemId.Key)
$Pageitem.File.CheckOut()
$Pageitem["ContentTypeId"] = $Global:ctToAdd.Id
$Pageitem.File.CheckIn("CheckIn automatically")
$Pageitem.File.Publish("Published automatically")
$Pageitem.Update(); //I would use SystemUpdate(false); this won't increase the file version.
$Pageitem = $PagesLibrary.GetItemById($deleteditemId.Key)
$Pageitem.ModerationInformation.Status = $deleteditemId.Value
$Pageitem.Update(); //Maybe SystemUpdate(false) here as well, depending on the requirements
```

Comment: I have added $Pageitem.Update(), but then i got this exception: Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "You cannot change moderation status and set other item properties at that same time."
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Test.ps1:127 char:37

Comment: After changing the metadata do an .Update() as well, then change the moderation information and do an .Update() again. Post the rest of your code please.

Comment: code updated now, please have a look

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thats work, but now I got another exception at first .Update(). Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "The file "http://somefile.aspx" is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before 
making changes." ... But i have checkedout as you see in code

Comment: You checked it out before changing the content type and then checked back in. Try checking in the file just before the last Update();

Comment: I put CheckIn just before last Update(), But now got another exception: Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "The file somefile.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|domain\administrator on 01 Mar 2016 13:47:03 +0100."